# No uname and gname in file.info R-package

Tags: r

I would like to get information about the last file user or creator of some files in `R` and tried to use `file.info` package to read uname but `file.info` does not provide such in my `3.5.1 R` version

```
    file.info("test.xlsx")
          size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
test.xlsx 8833 FALSE  666 2018-09-11 14:01:33 2018-09-11 14:01:33 2018-09-11 14:01:33  no
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide code snippet, what you have try to do so!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are on a Windows system.

From `?file.info` (bold-face mine):

> The uid, gid, uname and grname columns may not be supplied on a non-POSIX Unix-alike system, **and will not be on Windows**.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way access desired information?

Comment: My Windows knowledge is limited, but I think this is difficult (impossible?) as file ownership in Windows is tricky (i.e. a mess) (see e.g. [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/242307/information-about-a-file-or-directory)).